# making reusable text object

Tags: python, scripting, text-object

I want to simulate a multi-agent system with Blender. It's almost done, but I experience a problem.

System agents speak to each other by passing messages, and I want to pass messages between them. I considered a text object as container of these messages. There is no constraint on the number of agents.

I want to create one (or some) text object and reuse it many times, by only changing source and destination locations and body texts.

After some search, I realized, that there is no `data_path` that supports `keyframe_insert()` to change the body text. Beside that I found dynamic text, but my context is extremely different with that method's context.

I want to change text on every keyframe, and it depends on my simulation's input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [application handler](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_10/bpy.app.handlers.html?highlight=frame_change_pre#bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre) could be used to read subtitle data from your simulation module and display it by editing a text object.

```
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent


@persistent
def frame_change(arg):
    print("Load Handler:", bpy.data.filepath)
    t = bpy.data.objects["Text"]
    # here get the text you want to display
    label = ("Frame # %d" % bpy.context.scene.frame_current)
    t.data.body = label

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(frame_change)
```

Comment: Thanks stacker for your attention. However it could be a solution; but It is not efficient at all. because i have so many message and this function should fill these message in all frames. but i need to change message only in key frames.

Comment: please guide me if I am in wrong way

Comment: When you don't need to change the text content in frames just skip the code until you reach a 'keyframe'. Compared to the costs of rendering I wouldn't worry on efficiency.